# Program saying the ".move" function does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have some code to make a circle with a certain size location and color move around on the screen. This is my first attempt to do something like this with objects as the first time I did this I hardcoded it all.

```py
import tkinter as tk


class Head:

    def __init__(self, location, color, size, speed):
        self.location = location
        self.color = color
        self.size = size
        self.speed = speed


player = Head([375, 375], "orange4", 75, 5)


def movement(event, mover):
    key = event.keysym
    if key == "Right":
        window.move(mover, player.speed, 0)
    elif key == "Left":
        window.move(mover, -player.speed, 0)
    elif key == "Up":
        window.move(mover, 0, -player.speed)
    elif key == "Down":
        window.move(mover, 0, player.speed)


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Tour")
display = tk.Canvas(window, width=750, height=750)
display.pack()

player = display.create_oval((player.location[0] - (player.size / 2)), (player.location[1] - (player.size / 2)),
                             (player.location[0] + (player.size / 2)), (player.location[1] + (player.size / 2)),
                             fill=player.color)
window.bind_all("<Key>", lambda event: movement(event, mover=player))

window.mainloop()
```

When I run this code I get the error 
`AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'move'`
when I try to move with the arrow keys. I tried changing the `window` variable to the `player` and the `display` variables but it still did not work.

After what jasonharper and acw1668  said I changed to code to this:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Head:

    def __init__(self, location, color, size, speed):
        self.location = location
        self.color = color
        self.size = size
        self.speed = speed


player = Head([375, 375], "orange4", 75, 5)


def movement(event, mover):
    key = event.keysym
    if key == "Right":
        display.move(mover, player.speed, 0)
    elif key == "Left":
        display.move(mover, -player.speed, 0)
    elif key == "Up":
        display.move(mover, 0, -player.speed)
    elif key == "Down":
        display.move(mover, 0, player.speed)


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Tour")
display = tk.Canvas(window, width=750, height=750)
display.pack()

drawn_player = display.create_oval((player.location[0] - (player.size / 2)), (player.location[1] - (player.size / 2)),
                             (player.location[0] + (player.size / 2)), (player.location[1] + (player.size / 2)),
                             fill=player.color)
window.bind_all("<Key>", lambda event: movement(event, mover=player))

window.mainloop()
```

Now while there are no errors, the circle does not move. What is wrong?

Comment: Should be `display.move(...)` instead of `window.move(...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 I tried that and it still did not work.

Comment: And `player = display.create_oval(...)` will overwrite `player = Head(...)`.

Comment: You need to be calling `.move()` on the Canvas, not the window.  I suspect the reason that didn't work when you tried it is that you're trying to refer to two entirely different things with the name `player` - the one that's in effect when you actually try to move something no longer has the `speed` attribute.

Comment: @jasonharper I fixed everything you said, and while not giving me any errors, it just won't move the circle.

Comment: `mover=player` should be `mover=drawn_player`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the problem referring to the canvas in the `movement()` function, you also have two variables named `player` which will cause a new problem. I fix the latter by renaming the second one to `player_drawn` and all the references to it.

The code now works and moves the oval.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Head:

    def __init__(self, location, color, size, speed):
        self.location = location
        self.color = color
        self.size = size
        self.speed = speed


player = Head([375, 375], "orange4", 75, 5)


def movement(event, mover):
    key = event.keysym
    if key == "Right":
        display.move(mover, player.speed, 0)
    elif key == "Left":
        display.move(mover, -player.speed, 0)
    elif key == "Up":
        display.move(mover, 0, -player.speed)
    elif key == "Down":
        display.move(mover, 0, player.speed)

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Tour")
display = tk.Canvas(window, width=750, height=750)
display.pack()

drawn_player = display.create_oval((player.location[0] - (player.size / 2)),
                                   (player.location[1] - (player.size / 2)),
                                   (player.location[0] + (player.size / 2)),
                                   (player.location[1] + (player.size / 2)),
                                   fill=player.color)
window.bind_all("<Key>", lambda event: movement(event, mover=drawn_player))

window.mainloop()
```